# SKEmitterNode settings not appearing

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skemitternode

I created an sks file with the settings I want it to have, and when I call the method of adding the node onto the scene, the emitter particles don't look anything similar to what I set up. Any reason why?

```
-(SKEmitterNode *)emitParticles
{
SKEmitterNode *emitter = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"explosionParticles" ofType:@"sks"]];
emitter.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
emitter.targetNode = self.scene;
[self addChild:emitter];
return emitter;
}
```

[image: What I want]

What I want.

[image]

What I get.

Comment: You are adding emitter to self and also returning the emitter in your method. Are you adding the returned emitter a second time?

Comment: @sangony I did that, but then I removed the addChild in this method then created another method that allocated an SKEmitterNode that was equal to this method and added it, but I still got the same results.

Comment: Be more precise in what exactly your issue is. What results are you getting compared to what you are expecting.

Comment: @sangony Added pics.

Comment: Wow. Not sure what to say about the difference. The only thing I can suggest is for you to start from scratch. Create a standard emitter node and add it to your code until the emitter looks the same running in your code as it does emitter editor. There are a boat load of tutorials online if you get stuck. Once you have done that successfully, go back and try your custom emitter again.